# How do I connect to a private network from ethereum wallet?

Tags: ethereum

How do I connect to a private network from ethereum wallet? I was able to create a private network from geth command line using custom genesis file but now wanted my ethereum wallet to point to custom genesis file of the private network.Currently I am able to point my etherem wallet to either the mainnet or testnet but not private network.

I did find the following instructions on github mist browser Readme file but haven't been able to make much progress

*To run a privatenet you need to have geth installed separately and run it with the ipcpath flag:
$ geth --networkid 1234 --ipcpath /Users/you/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc --datadir ...*

Comment: Check [How to run Ethereum Wallet on a custom chain?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1018/87) or [How to connect mist to a testnet client?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/716/87) on Ethereum Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5):

1. Ensure your Ethereum Wallet is closing.
2. On your terminal.

   `$ geth --networkid "1234" --datadir "/some/other/path" --ipcpath "/Users/<username>/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc" console`
3. Reopen your Ethereum Wallet.

See: [Ethereum Wallet – Developer Preview](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/09/16/ethereum-wallet-developer-preview/)

If your want to reconnect to mainnet or testnet. Just type this "`$ geth console`" in your terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download [geth](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/) and [Ethereum mist wallet](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) , and install them.

Then go to the folder where you want to start the blockchain and follow these steps:

1. Start `command prompt` here

   - $ mkdir chaindata
   - $ geth --datadir=./chaindata init genesis.json
   - $ geth --datadir=./chaindata --fast --cache=1024
2. Start another `command prompt` here

   - $ geth attach
3. Start Ethereum Wallet. Make sure it opens in private network
4. for Mining

   - $ miner.start(3);
   - $ miner.stop();

You can get a video tutorial for the same [here](https://youtu.be/T3X7hfltr8c).

Hope it helps you!