# How can I connect EthereumMist with Private-Network on mac

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

I made Genesis block and turned on with *geth* 
like this

```
geth --identity "PrivateNetwork" --datadir "/Users/username/dev/ethereum/data" --port "30303" --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport "8123" --rpccorsdomain "*" --nodiscover --networkid 1900 --nat "any" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,miner" console
```

and... checked with this command: 
`eth.accounts'&'eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])`

It works, however I don't know how to connect with mist

I had tried `/Applications/Mist.app/Contents/MacOS/Mist --rpc http://localhost:8123` but what I can see is only this error message below

> Error starting up node and/or syncing Error: Couldn't start swarm process.
>       at Timeout.error [as _onTimeout] (/Applications/Mist.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js:451:23)
>       at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)"

I thought geth is CLI client and Mist is GUI client for ethereum net
I'm not sure even It is right

Do I need to turn on both of them? or turn on only one? please help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect to a private network from ethereum wallet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36661738/how-do-i-connect-to-a-private-network-from-ethereum-wallet)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you dont use the same rpcport for both of the applications. Use a different port for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you given wrong ip address. So when you run the command you will find below on your gth console.

> INFO [01-31|10:32:06] IPC endpoint opened:
>   /Users/divum/Desktop/local-network/geth.ipc  INFO [01-31|10:32:06]
>   HTTP endpoint opened: http://127.0.0.1:8545

Now try with

> **/Applications/Mist.app/Contents/MacOS/Mist --rpc [HTTP_END_POINT_URL]**

Replace HTTP_END_POINT_URL with your log http endpoint url.